# h1 tag inside div affecting all

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style headers inside a specific div. Problem is, it affects all headers in the page even those who are styled differently in another div.

My code that is causing the problem:

```
.container .guide-item .content h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #e1bb34;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

It is even overriding this:

```
.container .mainbar .newsfeed .contents article h4 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

Comment: Repeat your entire selector for every element, the comma seperates rules, not tags, so: `#guide-body h1, #guide-body h2, #guide-body h3, #guide-body h4, #guide-body h5` would be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector rule is incorrect. It should be:

```
.container .guide-item .content h1,
.container .guide-item .content h2,
.container .guide-item .content h3,
.container .guide-item .content h4,
.container .guide-item .content h5
{}
```

Comment: How could I overlook this. Thanks.